# 2 side by side divs. One fits to content, other expands full width

Tags: html, css

I would like to lay out two divs horizontally

```
parent div width=500px
- left div: shall grow horizontally to fit to contents (not more or less)
- right div: shall grow horizontally and take up all the space to the right edge
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Not a duplicate as the suggested duplicate requires a fixed width div and a expanding div while this question asks for two growing divs where the first one grows to content and the other one to available space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `flex` and `flex-grow`

```css
div {
display: flex;
width: 500px;
}
.grow {
flex-grow: 1;
background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>content</span>
  <span class="grow">grow</span>
</div>
```